# Breeze Server 1.4.14 Nuget Package Bad?

Tags: breeze, nuget-package

This is my first time to use Nuget, hold the judgements, and I wanted to verify that the following is an issue with the package itself.

In a brand new Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 Web API project.

Using Manage Nuget Packages dialog.

Installed Breeze Server - for Web API 2 (Version 1.4.14)

Installed Breeze Server - Context Provider for Entity Framework 6 (Version 1.4.14)

Wrote very simple breeze controller.

Build is a no go with the following error..

```
Assembly 'Breeze.WebApi2, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=f6085f1a45e2ac59' uses 'System.Web.Http.OData, Version=5.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than
referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http.OData, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    c:\Users\ccopelm2\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BreezeNugetTest\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.14\lib\Breeze.WebApi2.dll
```

Is this simply a broken package release?

To be clear, these are the only packages installed (unless the Web API template uses Nuget underneath the covers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with the Breeze.Server.WebApi2 Version: 1.4.14 package.

The following dependency definition is wrong:

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData(>=5.0 && < 6.0)

It should be >= 5.1

I updated Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package to version 5.2.0 and this fixed the issue by installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.2.0

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but was able to resolve it by updating the packages by right clicking on solution and selecting "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution".  Then selecting the "Updates" on the left menu, and clicking on Update All option.  It takes a while to update all referenced packages.  When completed, I Rebuild the solution and it compiled successfully.

Comment: Updating all packages is a big hammer, esp if you have several packages.